# Post a scheduled feed with Facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I try to post a scheduled feed, I send beyond the normal parameters I send published parameter and scheduled_publish_time. But the error message "Uncaught OAuthException: (# 100) The specified scheduled publish time is invalid." Already made ​​several changes to the format of the date I got no more success.

The last one I tried is:

`$date = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', '31/05/2013 22:00:00');
    $date = gmdate (DATE_ISO8601, mktime($date['hour'],$date['minute'],$date['second'],$date['month'],$date['day'],$date['year']));
    $content['scheduled_publish_time'] = strtotime($ date);`

Answer (score 4):

When I got the error it was because the scheduled_publish_time I was setting was less than 10 minutes.

According to facebook the "time when the page post should go live, this should be between 10 mins and 6 months from the time of publishing the post".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Also it must be a unix epoch timestamp and you don't have to worry about timezones either.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

I use the Facebook PHP SDK.

```
$post = $facebook->api("/v2.2/$pageName/$insight", 'post', $args);
```

and in my $args variables I have

```
$args  = array(
'scheduled_publish_time' => $epochTime,
'published' => 0
);
```

where $epochTime is something like this

```
$epochTime = strtotime("2015-04-07 09:00:00");
```

Comment: Hi @rhavey Did you were able to make it work ? I have a problem, my post is upload to facebook but not punlish when time=scheduled_publish_time. DId you had this problem ?

Comment: Hi @mcbjam, I don't have any issue with scheduling a post to a facebook page? I have updated my answer with some code snippets, I hope that helps you

Comment: Hi @rhavey. Ty for your feedback. I make it work i think after publish the app ith the basic permissions. Thanks.